# Homogeneous system of equations , and sub-set K of $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given K,L are sub-sets of $K^4$:

$K = \{(-5,8,14,0),(-1,4,2,4)\}, L = \{(0,1,-10,8),(0,3,-1,5)\}$

> Find a homogeneous system of equations that its solutions are Spanned by K.
>
> Also prove that L spans the solutions of that system too.

by "solutions" I mean if Ax=b then "x" are the solutions.

I believe the answers are ${{10} \over {3}}x+{{1} \over {3}}y+z=0 , {{8} \over {3}}x+{{-5} \over {3}}y -t = 0$

Any ideas how to approach this question? I believe this is very easy and something is tricky here.

Answer (score 1):

Both span(K) and span(L) are two-dimensional, so in $\mathbb{R}^4$ we expect to have two linear equations (since # of equations + # dimensions = dimension of larger vector space). Logically, there should be infinitely many possible pairs of equations that work, similar to how a line in 3D space has infinitely many planes passing through it.

Let one of the equations be  $ax + by + cz + dt = 0$. Since both of the basis vectors of $K$ satisfy this equation, we can sub them both in, which will give us two linear equations with a, b, c and d as unknowns. Solving these simultaneously will give us infinitely many possible combinations of a, b, c, d that the points of K satisfy. Any two particular of these should be an appropriate pair of equations.

To show that L spans the same set of solutions, you just have to check that both vectors satisfy both the equations, and note that the vectors are also linearly independent and so have the correct number for the dimension.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll check it out soon and update you.